# Why type struct BMPFILE_ is incomplete? in C

Tags: c, struct, incomplete-type

in **bmpfile.h** I define struct:

```
struct BMP_FILE_ {
  BMPHEADER header;
  BITMAPINFOHEADER dib;
  unsigned char channels;
  rgb_px_t **pixels;
  rgb_px_t *pal;
} BMPFILE_, *pBMPFILE;
typedef struct BMPFILE_ BMPFILE;
BMPFILE * bmp_create(uint32_t width, uint32_t height, uint32_t depth, uint32_t fillcolor);
```

**bmpfile.c** defines function bmp_create_standard_color_table

```
static void
bmp_create_standard_color_table(BMPFILE *bmpfile)
{
switch (bmpfile->dib.depth) ...
}
```

Error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type on line with switch ...

First of all, why the type BMPFILE_ is incomplete?

It's not clear to me why I need another name for type BMPFILE_.

```
typedef struct BMPFILE_ BMPFILE;
```

Originally I wanted to skip it and use just BMPFILE_ as return type for function bmp_create, but there was an error that the BMPFILE_ is unknow.
I believe this means that the type is incomplete, but I added the

```
typedef struct BMPFILE_ BMPFILE;
```

and the result is that it can pass the header through compiler, but there is another error in the .c file. But I cannot find out why this happens.
In main function I tried to use this:
`BMPFILE bmpfile;` instead of `BMPFILE * bmpfile;`
and again it tells me I cannot do it because the type is incomplete. But definitely I cannot find why it is incomplete. Because I compared it with another very similar type declared as `PNG_DATA data;` (*libpng*). None problems with data type, even that both are having similar structure. I even tried to remove the sub-structs from BMPFILE_ (BMPFILE) to test if it will be complete or incomplete type and it was still incomplete.

Comment: Typo `BMPFILE_` vs `BMP_FILE_`

Comment: So do you want to say, that this is the cause of the incomplete type? new struct name should be `typedef struct BMP_FILE_ BMPFILE;`? Can somebody explain why I need the new name for struct and cannot return type BMPFILE_ directly?

Comment: Read your code again: `typedef struct BMPFILE_ BMPFILE;`

Comment: Can you answer my question?

Answer (score 1):

You are confused by using too many similar names (e.g. `BMPFILE_` vs `BMP_FILE_` ....), which makes your code unreadable. And you made a typo, which confuses the compiler.

Forward declare

```
struct BMP_FILE_st;
```

Then

```
typedef struct BMP_FILE_st BMP_FILE;
```

Then define your structure:

```
struct BMP_FILE_st {
  BMPHEADER header;
  BITMAPINFOHEADER dib;
  unsigned char channels;
  rgb_px_t **pixels;
  rgb_px_t *pal;
};
```

And *don't* make a typedef for pointer; So code `BMP_FILE*`, e.g. declare a pointer variable

```
BMP_FILE* ptr_bmp_file;
```

and an aggregate variable:

```
BMP_FILE my_bmp_file_struct;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code, which is greatly clear. But I also need to understand why the type is incomplete because I have one more type PNG_DATA data which is very similar to this one and I don't need to use pointer in declaration of that object